# Is there any argument to be passed to CGMiner\AntMiner S2 to reserve amounts of hashing power for specific workloads?

Tags: asic, cgminer, miner-configuration

I have an AntMiner S2 (1TH/s) and I'd like to mine both on BTC and NMC.

Would that be possible, for instance, to use 50% of power just for BTC workloads and the other 50% for NMC?

**EDIT:**

What exactly is the Intensity parameter?

> `ckolivas` [says](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=87022.msg956792#msg956792):
>
> Intensity is the amount of work in one go the GPU has to do before it can return its results.

But I'm still confused: what is it in practice?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the easiest way to achieve this would just be, e.g., to mine BTC at full speed for 12 hours hours, then stop it and mine NMC for 12 hours. A simple cron job or something similar could accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play around with the `intensity` flag (`-I`). You can set it to a low number (e.g. 4/5) or dynamic (`-I d`). I don't think there is an option to limit to exactly 50%, but you can try to play with this setting, and look what happens. If you set both CGMiners to dynamic, maybe they will divide the hashing power equally, and that is exactly what you want.

Comment: So there's also no setting I can adjust to set the GHashes I want to throw in one pool or another (both in CGminer or the AntMiner interface)?

Comment: Afaik there is no such option, and cant find it too.